# How to pass local video file as a prop to ReactPlayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I'm using [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) component for this.

I have file 1 where I'm storing some data as an array, including a local video.

```
import videoSample from "../assets/videos/sample-video.mov";

export const Data = {
  ProjectList: [
    {
      title: "My title",
      desc: "Some description",
      videoUrl: { videoSample },
      sourceUrl: "https:// ... ",
    },
  ],
};
```

File 2 takes the array and maps each item to a React component called `ProjectDetail`.

```
function MappingFunction() {
  return (
    <>
      {Data.ProjectList.map((project, index) => (
          <ProjectDetail key={index} {...project} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Finally, this is file 3 which contains `ProjectDetail`. It takes the array item as props. `videoUrl` is passed to the [ReactPlayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) component.

```
export default function ProjectDetail(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ReactPlayer 
           url={props.videoUrl}  // does not work!
           width="500px"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>  // works
        <p>{props.desc}</p>     // works
        <button 
          onClick={() => { window.open(props.sourceUrl, "_blank"); }}  // works
        > Click to see more
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

`title`, `desc` and `sourceUrl` are working fine, but I don't understand `videoUrl` doesn't. I tried looking up an answer but was unsuccessful.

If I import `videoSample` in file 3 directly, it works fine, but not when passed as a prop from outside. What am I missing?

Comment: fix `videoUrl: { videoSample }` to `videoUrl: videoSample` in the first code block

Comment: Oh wow, what an awfully simple solution! I can't believe I spent so much time on this. Thank you @boop_the_snoot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. All I needed to do was removing the curly brackets.

`videoUrl: { videoSample }` -> `videoUrl: videoSample`